# How can I find the source code of my Joomla site?

Tags: php, html, web-services, joomla, web

My site is run by joomla/php. How can I locate a specific file of my website for template modification of the outputted HTML?

Answer (score 1):

/templates/[your template name]/index.php

Answer (score 1):

Joomla is CMS and therefore there is not 1 specific file but multiple files depending on what exactly you wish to edit. It's built up of extensions ( *Components, Modules and Plugins* ), each of which contains HTML markup (however not all plugins do though).

To edit the main structure of your website, you will need to edit the following file:

```
YOUR_SITE/templates/YOUR_TEMPLATE/index.php
```

the following shows which files to edit for the extensions:

**Modules:**

```
YOUR_SITE/modules/mod_helloworld/tmpl/default.php
or
YOUR_SITE/modules/mod_helloworld/mod_helloworld.php
```

**Components:**

```
YOUR_SITE/components/com_helloworld/views/VIEW_NAME/tmpl/default.php
```

Hope this helps